# The click button is not working when assigned a redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I need a little help with this redux problem that I am encountering. Here, I have an APP.js code that called the action from a file called duck.js.

```
import {
  selectBaseCurrency,
  selectExchangeCurrency,
  selectExhangeRate,
  setBaseCurrency, //calling this action
  initialState,
} from "./configureStore/duck";
```

In this code, I have specified the mapDispatchToProp to dispatch the action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=> ({
  onClick: () => dispatch(setBaseCurrency(ownProps.baseCurrency)),
});
```

I've also connected it to the connect().

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    exchangeRate: selectExhangeRate(state),
    exchangeCurrency: selectExchangeCurrency(state),
    baseCurrency: selectBaseCurrency(state)
  }), mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

However, for some reason, when I click on the button, the value is not updated accordingly to the input. The button code looks like following:

```
 <button onClick={() => onClick("USD")}>
        Change Currency Value
 </button>
```

Have I missed out a code to dispatch this correctly? What could be the problem with it.

Here below, I attach the full duck and also the App.js for more reference.

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectBaseCurrency,
  selectExchangeCurrency,
  selectExhangeRate,
  setBaseCurrency, //calling this action
  // setExchangeCurrency, 
  // setExchangeRate, 
  initialState,
} from "./configureStore/duck";

const App = ({
  exchangeRate,
  exchangeCurrency,
  baseCurrency,
  onClick
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <b>Exchange Rate</b>: {exchangeRate}
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>Exchange Currency</b>: {exchangeCurrency}
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>Base Currency</b>: {baseCurrency}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => onClick("USD")}>
        Change Currency Value
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
App.propTypes = {
  exchangeRate: PropTypes.number,
  exchangeCurrency: PropTypes.string,
  baseCurrency: PropTypes.string,
  setBaseCurrency: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // setExchangeCurrency: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  // setExchangeRate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
App.defaultProps = {
  exchangeRate: initialState.exchangeRate,
  exchangeCurrency: initialState.exchangeCurrency,
  baseCurrency: initialState.baseCurrency
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,ownProps)=> ({
  onClick: () => dispatch(setBaseCurrency(ownProps.baseCurrency)),
  // on: setExchangeCurrency,
  // setExchangeRate: setExchangeRate
});

export default connect(
  state => ({
    exchangeRate: selectExhangeRate(state),
    exchangeCurrency: selectExchangeCurrency(state),
    baseCurrency: selectBaseCurrency(state)
  }), mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

duck.js

```
import { defineAction } from "redux-define";
import { createAction, handleActions } from "redux-actions";

export const initialState = {
  exchangeRate: 3.06,
  baseCurrency: "SGD",
  exchangeCurrency: "MYR"
};

//Action-types
export const SET_EXCHANGE_RATE = defineAction("SET_EXCHANGE_RATE");
export const SET_BASE_CURRENCY = defineAction("SET_BASE_CURRENCY");
export const SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY = defineAction("SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY");

//Action-creators
export const setExchangeRate = createAction(
  SET_EXCHANGE_RATE,
  params => params
);
export const setExchangeCurrency = createAction(
  SET_EXCHANGE_CURRENCY,
  params => params
);
export const setBaseCurrency = createAction(
  SET_BASE_CURRENCY,
  params => params
);

//reducer
const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [setExchangeRate]: (state, { exchangeRate }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeRate
    }),
    [setExchangeCurrency]: (state, { exchangeCurrency }) => ({
      ...state,
      exchangeCurrency
    }),
    [setBaseCurrency]: (state, { baseCurrency }) => ({
      ...state,
      baseCurrency
    })
  },
  initialState
);
export default reducer;

//Selector
export const selectExhangeRate = state => state.exchangeRate;
export const selectExchangeCurrency = state => state.exchangeCurrency;
export const selectBaseCurrency = state => state.baseCurrency;
```

Edit : As additional info, here is my sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/todoapp-with-redux-and-normalized-store-jkp8z

and here is my github link: 
https://github.com/sc90/test-sandbox

Comment: Just simply, debug by trying to log your on click event on console to confirm if your click event is working at all!

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Are you not seeing it dispatched in redux-dev-tools or something? You should do the following: confirm the click is working in your `mapDispatchToProps` using a console message or debugger statement before you `dispatch(setBaseCurrency(ownProps.baseCurrency))`, then from there, I would add a log message or debugger statement to your reducer to see if the action is making there.

It's hard to know without seeing more code, but the code you posted doesn't seem to have any red flags to me so it might be elsewhere like your store configuration.

Comment: I'll try to debug first and see but if it helps, here's my git link: https://github.com/sc90/test-sandbox

Comment: I can at least confirm that the button is calling a console.log but doesn't triggered the dispatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are at least two issues here, I'll try to explain them one by one, I'm not sure how these frameworks you're using interact but here are a few points that will at least fix your issue.

1. Your reducer is trying to extract `{ baseCurrency }` but this is not a property of your action. You instead need to extract the `payload` here, like this: `{ payload }`, this `payload` value will contain your `baseCurrency`, and to properly save it in the reducer you should return `{ ...state, baseCurrency: payload }`
2. Your selectors are trying to read directly from the `state` variable, but this one contains your reducers under the keys you sent to `combineReducers`, in your case you called your reducer `reducer`, thus you need to select state like this `state => state.reducer.baseCurrency`

See my fork of your Sandbox where I've fixed the baseCurrency case for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/todoapp-with-redux-and-normalized-store-ih79q

Comment: If I can give you the stars, I will give you the stars. Thank you very much for your guidance. :)